# Deleting csv file java

Tags: java, csv, file-io

I have a CSV file that I just read the values from, and have another where I put those values and also update. I will like to delete the first CSV, and rename the updated CSV. This is what I have:

```
try
{
    if(file.delete())
    {
        System.out.println("Successfully deleted!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Delete Operation didn't work.");
    }

    newFile.renameTo(new File("Book1.csv"));
}

catch (IOException ioe)
{
    System.out.println("ERROR. IO Exception: " + ioe.toString());
}
```

I have checked for myself, and for some reason, the delete function doesn't always work.

Comment: Please check if you have permission to delete files?

Comment: Ensure that your CSV file is closed after reading.

Comment: Any error or exceptions ?

Comment: Yes. I'm catching a IO Exception. I closed the csv after reading.

Comment: @codeMaker How do I check for permissions?

Comment: @user2026615: make changes what dbyrne has suggested and then post `stacktrace`, so others can understand why can't you delete the file?

Comment: I found a way to delete the file. You just need to close every form of reader you have on the file e.g Scanner, BufferedReader, FileInputStream etc. With these closed, call the delete method, and it does delete!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more information, its impossible to say why your delete is failing.  However, at the very least you should check to make sure the delete succeeds:

```
if(file.delete()) {
    //Handle success
} else {
    //Handle failure
}
```

Comment: And all I get is the failure, that's what i don't understand.

Comment: @user2026615: POst the stacktrace, so others can understand better

Comment: Also, are you using java7? If so the java.nio.file.Files class has a much improved API for dealing with files. Especially by throwing exceptions when things go wrong instead of returning booleans, so you can more easily diagnose exactly what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing similar issue , it turned out i havent closed the csv file after reading.
Closed it and problem solved :-)...